# Push changes from my branch to different branch in a different remote

Tags: git

I have two repos and I have added second repo as remote (origin2). Can I push changes from origin1/branch1 to origin2/any_branch?

1. I changed files in my origin/branch1
2. Committed the changes
3. git remote update
4. git push origin2 origin2/any_branch tells me Everything up to date.

Comment: I think instead of your last step `git push origin2 origin1/branch1` would be the correct step. (I am not so sure... so make backups before trying it...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
git push origin2 branch1:any_branch
```

From `man git push`:

> ```
> <refspec>...
>   Specify what destination ref to update with what source object. 
>   The format of a <refspec> parameter is an optional plus +, followed
>   by the source object <src>, followed by a colon :, followed by the 
>   destination ref <dst>.
> ```

Answer (score 1):

First, check out `origin1/branch1` locally:

```
% git checkout branch1 
Branch branch1 set up to track remote branch branch1 from origin.
Switched to a new branch 'branch1'
```

Then push to `origin2/any_branch`:

```
% git push origin2 branch1:any_branch
Counting objects: 3, done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 238 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To path/to/origin2
 * [new branch]      branch1 -> any_branch
```

Reference:

- [`git push`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-push)

Answer (score 1):

From [GitHub](https://help.github.com/articles/pushing-to-a-remote):

> To push a local branch to an established remote, you need to issue the
>   command:
>
> git push  REMOTENAME BRANCHNAME
>
> This is most typically invoked as
>
> **git push origin master**.
>
> If you would like to give the branch a
>   different name on the upstream side of the push, you can issue the
>   command:
>
> **git push  REMOTENAME LOCALBRANCHNAME:REMOTEBRANCHNAME**
>
> If your local copy of the repository is out of sync with (behind) the
>   upstream repository you are pushing to, you will be presented with a
>   message saying "This branch can not be fast forwarded." This merely
>   means that you must retrieve the upstream changes before you are able
>   to push your local changes.